# Can I answer a lore question with information from non-RPG media?

Tags: discussion, answers

Say that I see a question about the *Shadowrun* setting. I happen to know that the answer to the question can't be found in the RPGs, but it is answered in the novels and/or video games. Can I use that as an answer?

To give an example, over on Sci-fi/Fantasy Stack Exchange, there was [a question about the legitimate uses for decking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166256/13217). [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166262/13217) relied on the  *Shadowrun* novels.

> As documented in the Shadowrun novels such as *[Never Deal with a Dragon](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Source:Never_Deal_With_A_Dragon)*, the virtual reality access methods used in Decking was standard for corporations, as Sam has a (very basic) Avatar for use at Renraku. [...]

Would that answer have been acceptable on this site? Or do we need to stick with questions and answers that are related to RPG books?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering from related media is fine, but be careful to be explicit, as how things work in the RPG is not always completely aligned with the a) different mechanics in video games and b) fictional liberties taken in novels.  For some questions, answers from those might be appropriate and for others they may not be. Lore questions should be safe (though even there, there can be splits between different continuities, like the Shadowfist card game world split from the Feng Shui RPG world...)

Comment: So you are saying that it's okay to answer from other media so long as any differences from RPG information are made clear?

Comment: Yes.  If you're not sure if there's a difference, then it might be best not to answer and let someone who knows the RPG info better answer. But if you are conversant with the RPG lore and know it's likely a gap and likely consistent, go for it.

Comment: Specially when those liberties are backported in the game. C'mn, [half-elves wielding moonblades](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Arilyn%27s_moonblade)... give me a break. #rant